# Liquibase changesets can not be rerun

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

**Our Liquibase script can not be rerun because underlying column is already gone**

Consider the following changesets:

1. A table "foo" is created, and "domain" is one of the columns in this table;
2. A constraint (in form of an index) is placed on the column "domain";
3. Column "domain" is dropped from the table "foo".

Now when we try to rerun all liquibase scripts (over already existing DB structure), changeset 2 fails with

```
[ERROR]      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: column "domain" named in key does not exist
```

all because the "domain" column in the actual DB is already gone before changeset 2 is run.

Is there any better way to make these changesets runnable other than recreating the "domain" column in the table so that all 3 changesets can run?

- there are hundreds of changesets in the system besides the 2 above;
- the solution is strongly preferred to avoid any manual steps because there are dozens of environments in which the changesets must be rerun;
- In a perfect world, a developer would have placed a **preConditions** on changeset 2 to check that not only the index is missing, but the underlying column exists, but we have to deal with what we have. It is my understanding that rewriting existing changesets is strongly discouraged in liquibase.

Comment: The problem is why do you need to rerun every `changeset`? Even when the DB is already up-to-date with all the changes!

Comment: @ray Our particular problem is that in one set of our environments, liquibase  scripts were run from a wrong directory. Now when we try to move them to the right directory, liquibase run fails, because file moving to another directory is perceived as a change. Thus, we decided to rerun all liquibase scripts from the new (actually, an old) directory.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment, your problem is changing `liquibase` scripts directory location.

What actually happens is `liquibase` will compare `liquibase` script's relative path when executing these `changesets` in your scripts. You can find this relative path in the `databasechangelog` table and under column `filename`.

First thing you should understand is problem is not with the `checksum`. So it will not solve your problem.

The easiest thing that you can do is change the values in column `filename` in table `databasechangelog`. If you have more than one `liquibase` script files I suggest you to change them one by one. Simple sql query like this can do the job.

```
update databasechangelog set filename='<new_filename>' where filename='<old_filename>'
```

***Note: You can make the situation worse if you did it wrong. Make sure you double check everything before you make any changes.***

Comment: Thank you! I've considered "update databasechangelog" a hack that is better to be avoided (as I mentioned, we have hundreds of changesets and dozens of environments), but maybe that is a lesser evil here.

Comment: Well that a one way to put it. Personally I think it won't be a problem if you know what you doing. Yeah its lot of work, I agree with you there. But it lot less compare to changing all the `changesets`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a preCondition to the changeSets #2 and #3 to check that the `domain` column exists, e.g.:

```
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <columnExists tableName="foo" columnName="domain"/>
    </preConditions>
```

If these changeSets will start to fail with the "different checksum error", than you can always provide the new checksum or just add `<validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>`.
This way you'll be able to run these changeSets in all environments you need.

Rewriting the changeSets is discouraged, but writing preConditions for the changeSets is quire encouraged.

Comment: Thanks! This is something that we can do. Only if we go to "<validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>" - can we ever go back?

Comment: Go back to what?  "<validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>" means that liqubiase won't check for the chengeSet's checksum, so if your changeset changes (which is discouraged) liquibase will not notice that. But if you add preconditions only, then the checksum of the changeset will not be changed, so it shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I mean, would adding/removing <validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum> change the checksum again? If it would, then once we add this property, it can never be removed, per my understanding.

Comment: No, specifying `validCheckSum` won't change the checksum